# How to link MySQL to html5

Tags: html, sql, database, web

I create a website by using HTML5 and CSS languages , how can I link website with sql database ?
how
what the best and shortest way ?

thank you so much

Comment: There is no "best" way, and a good way might not be the "shortest" way.

Comment: You need to learn at least one server-side language. HTML5 and CSS themselves have nothing to do with databases, and you cannot connect them directly to one. Please look around for a tutorial in PHP, Ruby, Perl, Python, node.js, or some other language, then ask for help when you get stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Alone HTML5 wont let you connect to mysql DB. But yes, the server side javascript can help you to achieve what you are trying to do. There are node.js modules available to connect and query mysql DB. You can install node.js and then you can write the backend in Javascript.

There are other Server-Side Languages such ASP.Net, PHP, etc that you can choose from.

https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules#wiki-db-mysql

Or Try this:

[**HTML5 - Web SQL Database**](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_web_sql.htm)

Comment: This answer is misleading to the extent that it implies that node.js is the only option. Many other server-side technologies will also fit the bill.

Comment: Yes, There are many and I am not saying Node.js is only the option. It is one of the options.

Comment: It sounds like you are when you say, "You have to install node.js." You might want to clarify your answer.

Comment: Yes sure, will modify. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

To link the website with a **SQL Database** you need to do a **Server Side script**.This is a technique used in website design which involves embedding scripts in an HTML source code which results in a user's request to the server website being handled by a script running on the server-side before the server responds to the request. Scripts can be written in any of a number of server-side scripting languages that are available but I'll suggest you to use [**PHP**](http://www.w3schools.com/php/) its simple, easy and fast.